# DAX Calculate the YOY score change

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I need to calculate the difference between each year and plot that change in a line graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power BI your pivoted (Excel) table will get you nowhere. Be sure to unpivot all your "YYYY Score" columns in PowerQuery first. This should give you something like:

[image]

Next create an explicit measure for your score:

```
Max Score = MAX('Table'[Score])
```

With this you can now create your desired "Score Change":

```
Score Change =
VAR cursor =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Year] )
VAR prevYear =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Year] ),
        'Table'[Year] < cursor
    )
VAR prevScore =
    CALCULATE (
        [Max Score],
        'Table'[Year] = prevYear
    )
RETURN
    IF ( NOT ( ISBLANK ( prevScore ) ),
        [Max Score] - prevScore
    )
```

Finally put the results in a matrix visual or a line chart:

[image]