# How to sort multiple x Axis for hierarchical bar chart Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a hierarchical bar chart, I want to sort in such a way that it shows Plan then Actual, starting from Jan 2020 to Sep 2020.

Problem is when I sort it ascending or descending. It sorts both Month and Status(Plan and Actual)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUMQY.png)

Sample table data:

```
Quarter Month   Status  Debit   Digital Internal    IVT Risk
Q1  Jan'22  Plan    57  92  33  9   60
        Actuals 46  92  33  9   60
    Feb'22  Plan    58  72  36  8   65
        Actuals 50  72  37  8   65
    Mar'22  Plan    71  28  30  22  2
        Actuals 44  28  29  22  2
```

Comment: This is a follow-up on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755313/how-to-create-slicer-from-column-name/73761092#73761092

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rather that your artificial month format "Jan'22" is sorted in alphabetical order. So you have to introduce a separate Month table and then sort your month by order. (Or even better: Use a reasonable ISO date format right from the beginning.)

The Months table has to have a relation to the data table:

[image]

In the bar chart you use the sorted Month from the Months table instead:

[image]